# Problem with data augmentation only on train set!

Tags: keras, image-classification, data-augmentation

So I want to augment my data but unfortunately, I don't have an individual folder for train and validation set,  and of course, I want to only augment the train set but if I use this:

```
data = keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=(1/255.),horizontal_flip=True,vertical_flip=True,validation_split=0.2)
```

this way I can split the sets but the augmentation would also apply to validation data too, so what should I do?

I should also mention that I'm reading the data from the directory using `flow_from_directory`

Comment: Is there anything stopping you from having individual folders?

Comment: @ValentinCalomme actually I'm a bit new to this field and I want to have a random split, I just don't know if there's a way to do a random split and put them into a separate folder

Comment: You need to put train/val in different folders. You can simply randomly sample from a list containing all images. https://github.com/Bixi81/Python-ml/blob/master/randomly_sample_files.py